Brightness control and Bluetooth not working on Ubuntu 24.10! please help :'(
Brightness control and bluetooth not working in ubuntu 24.10! I tried many methods on youtube but nothing... Can I do this in 24.04? Is this version not supposed to??? It's a Ryzen 5 laptop from HP. The computer is fine, probably the software is causing this. Thank you very much in advance to everyone who will give me an answer.
